# Which test to compare Vitamin D serum level between malignant and benign tissues

Tags: correlation, anova, t-test, continuous-data, paired-data

I have Vitamin D levels for both malignant and benign tumor types and I need to compare them. Which test should I use, unpaired t test ?

Another question; I have also PSA level ( also continuous data like vitamin D) that I need to investigate the relationship between PSA and vitamin D for both tumor types, which test should I use ?

Thank you, sorry for long questions. The first question is more essential.

Comment: If you are interested in comparing the means, then yes, a t-test is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site.

For the first question - well, it's certainly a possible test. The unpaired t-test compares the means on two groups. Is that what you want to do? If so, then the t-test is a place to start, but you have to check the assumptions. However, maybe you don't want to compare the means. You  might want to compare the variances or various quantiles or something. (E.g. if you think one group is more likely to have a vit D deficiency, you might want to look at the lower quantiles of vit D).

The second question looks like it should be some form of regression.

Comment: Thank you for your response, exactly I want to analyze the deficiency on malignant tumours at the lover quantiles. What would you suggest me ? Thank you.

Comment: Quantile regression.